# Zend Framework: How to check an additional column while using DbTable Auth Adapter?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-auth

Currently, I'm getting a regular `DbTable Auth Adapter`:

```
protected function _getAuthAdapter($formData)
{       
    $dbAdapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($dbAdapter);
    $authAdapter->setTableName('users')
        ->setIdentityColumn('username')
        ->setCredentialColumn('password');
    $authAdapter->setIdentity($formData['username']);
    $authAdapter->setCredential(md5($formData['password']));
    return $authAdapter;
}
```

But I want to check an additional column in the database (`IsActive` for example). I don't know if this can be done with the adapter. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar situation, and I extended the `Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable` to satisfy my needs:

```
class My_Auth_Adapter_DbTable extends Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable
{
    protected $_customerIdColumn = 'customer_id';
    protected $_customerId = false;

    public function setCustomerId($id) {
        $this->_customerId = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getCustomerId() {
        return ($this->_customerId !== false) ? $this->_customerId : '';
    }

    public function _authenticateCreateSelect() {
        $dbSelect = parent::_authenticateCreateSelect();
        $dbSelect->where($this->_zendDb->quoteIdentifier($this->_customerIdColumn, true) . ' = ?',
            $this->getCustomerId());
        return $dbSelect;
    }
}
```

I then use it like this:

```
public function getAuthAdapter(array $params)
{
    $authAdapter = new My_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(
        $params['db_adapter'],
        'users',
        'username',
        'password',
        '? AND active = 1'
    );

    $authAdapter->setIdentity($params['username'])
        ->setCustomerId($params['customer_id'])
        ->setCredential($params['password']);

    return $authAdapter;
}
```

Comment: In Zend 3 class `Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable` is changed to `Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable\CredentialTreatmentAdapter`. Class `DbTable` as far as can I see is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I use two columns for my Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable, and it looks like this:

```
$authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(
  Zend_Registry::get('database'),
  "user",
  "username",
  "password_hash", // column 1
  "MD5( CONCAT(?,password_salt) )" // column 2
);
```

When authenticating, the SQL ends up looking like this:

```
SELECT `user`.*, 
(CASE WHEN `password_hash` = MD5( CONCAT('password entered',password_salt) )
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `zend_auth_credential_match`
FROM `user` WHERE (`username` = 'username entered')
```

So, that checks an additional column, `password_salt`, and for me it works well.  I don't know if that helps you, as I don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't really understand this...Can you please expand upon your answer? Specifically on the order of params and how it works.

Comment: It does not check another column but combines it with the password and does a hash on that..

I think there is currently no way of checking an extra field like valid = 1 or something :(

Answer (score 0):

The included Auth Adapater Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable does not allow you to check an additional column.  You could extend the Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable class and add another column.  You will have to add a member variable for the value of new field $_otherFieldValue and a public function setMemberField($value).  Finally, you would have to override:

```
protected function _authenticateCreateSelect()
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question may be already solved but you can also solve this without needing to extend the class, use the getDbSelect() method and add the where clause to it:

```
    $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(Model_Users::getDefaultAdapter());

    $authAdapter->setTableName('users');
    $authAdapter->setIdentityColumn('email');
    $authAdapter->setCredentialColumn('password')->setCredentialTreatment('md5(?)');
    $authAdapter->setIdentity($email);
    $authAdapter->setCredential($password);
    $authAdapter->getDbSelect()->where('active = 1');
```